# How to write Vue data in html properties?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

For example, this will throw a Vue error:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/{{ form.screw.drive_image }}" >
```

I'm writing `{{ form.screw.drive_image }}` in the src prop.

It's not clear from Vue's warnings what I should do to solve.

Any idea?

Comment: what is the error warning?

Comment: A generic [Vue warn]: Error compiling template

Comment: `:src="'<?=get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/' + form.screw.drive_image" >`

Comment: @Derek that works thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Derek (see comments above), the correct answer is:

```
:src="'<?= get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/' + form.screw.drive_image"
```

Please note the followings:

- `:src` is a shorthand for `v-bind:src`
- `<?=` is a shorthand for `<?php echo [...]`
- In this case Vue's data doesn't need braces
- Computation in Vue's props is javascript, so in :src we are using `+` to concatenate

Comment: Also reminder that Vue template `{{...}}` binding doesn't work in attributes, you need to use the `:` / `v-bind:` shortcut to denote an attribute that needs calculating/parsing vs a static string.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the [`v-bind` shorthand](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand), from the documentation:

> Dynamically bind one or more attributes, or a component prop to an expression.

The format:

```
<img :src="'some_string' + some_data">
```

The final product:

```
<img :src="'<?=get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/' + form.screw.drive_image">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
<img v-bind:src="form.screw.drive_image" />
```

and change the value of ***form.screw.drive_image*** to include ***get_stylesheet_directory_uri()***